# How to use accumulator to count the records that have no matching items in leftOuterJoin?

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, accumulator

Spark `accumulators` are a great way to get useful information about an operation over an RDD.

My problem is the following: I want to perform a join between two datasets, called, e.g. `events` and `items` (where the events are unique and involve items, and both are keyed by `item_id` which is primary for `items`)

What works is this:

```
val joinedRDD = events.leftOuterJoin(items)
```

One possible way to know how many events did not have matching items is to write:

```
val numMissingItems = joinedRDD.map(x => if (x._2._2.isDefined) 0 else 1).sum
```

My question is: is there a way to obtain this count with an accumulator? I dont want to go through the RDD just to do the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you could use the `cogroup` signature and then do the logic that `leftOuterJoin` performs by your self, and in the no match case increment the accumulator. However, its important to note, that since this is a transformation, it is possible (for example if a task fails / is recomputed) that your accumulator *may* over count the number of records, although generally not by a lot. Its up to you if that is acceptable.

Comment: duplicating the `leftOuterJoin` Logic could indeed work. Thanks.

Re the comment about over counting - my understanding is that failed tasks do not cause double counting. If I cause the entire stage to be recomputed, that's on me (and can be avoided using caching)

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, but what benefits is this solution provides compare to this : joinedRDD.filter { case (id, (label, None)) => true case _ => false }.foreach(x => accum += 1) ?

Comment: So by having the accumulator updated inside of the join logic, you can avoid having to do an explicit additional pass over the data.

Comment: @Holden If accumulator state is reduced after task completion, why would task failure lead to over-counting?

Comment: So I perhaps played a bit fast/lose on task failure/recompute but if a partition needs to be recomputed it may be double counted. As @Amir mentioned caching can help this (although not entirely avoid it since sometimes workers die, cached data gets evicted, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Answering based on @Holden's answer, to the request of @Francis Toth:

This is based on spark's leftOuterJoin, where the only addition is the part `missingRightRecordsAcc += 1`.

Function definition:

```
object JoinerWithAccumulation {
  def leftOuterJoinWithAccumulator[K: ClassTag, V, W](left: PairRDDFunctions[K, V],
                                                      right: RDD[(K, W)],
                                                      missingRightRecordsAcc: Accumulator[Int])
  : RDD[(K, (V, Option[W]))] = {
    left.cogroup(right).flatMapValues { pair =>
      if (pair._2.isEmpty) {
        pair._1.iterator.map(v => { missingRightRecordsAcc += 1; (v, None)})
      } else {
        for (v <- pair._1.iterator; w <- pair._2.iterator) yield (v, Some(w))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val events = sc.textFile("...").parse...keyBy(_.getItemId)
val items = sc.textFile("...").parse...keyBy(_.getId)
val acc = sc.accumulator(0)

val joined = JoinerWithAccumulation.leftOuterJoinWithAccumulator(eventsKV,adsKV,acc)

println(acc.value) // 0, since there were no actions performed on the rdd 'joined'

println(joined.count) // = events.count ; this triggers an action
println(acc.value) // = number of records in joined without a matching record from 'items'
```

(The hardest part was to get the function definition right, with the `ClassTag` etc..)